# Можно ли узнать работает ли сторонняя программа с данной директорией?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Предположим, есть какой-то сторонний и древний софт без какого-либо API для взаимодействия, которому на вход подается некоторые директории с файлами и он их колбасит считывая какие-то метрики без изменения самих файлов.

Так вот, можно ли как-то из своей программы пасти ее и понять над какой директорией она выполняет операции чтения?

Интересует возможность получения такой информации, как в сценариях когда программа колбасит папку на локальном ПК, так и тогда когда программа работает с ресурсом на файловой шаре.

Comment: Руссинович делал в своё время [filemon](https://ab57.ru/filemon.html) так что вероятно API для слежения есть, но вот если ли .net обёртка или вам придётся самому добавлять...

Comment: @AK Ну в Net есть FileSystemWatcher, но он только изменения мониторит.

Comment: Единственный вариант, который знаю - это искать все файлы, которые задействованы в процессах и проверять, не лежат ли они в этой папке. Это довольно трудоемкий процесс. И то, скорее всего, будет работать только для исполняемых файлов

Comment: [Is it possible to watch a file, to see when it is being read?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29846773/2881286)

Comment: Для этого существует Process Monitor от SysInternals. Он работает при помощи kernel-mode драйвера. API в него вроде нет

Comment: Нутром чую, что это возможно с помощью ETW.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Может быть, но что-то ничего не гуглится=(

Comment: Мне кажется, журнал аудита с записями о попытках доступа к объектам (файловой системы) отлично подходят для этих целей: как для файл-сервера, так и для локального компа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такая мощная технология: Event Tracing for Windows (ETW). Она может собирать огромное количество всевозможных событий. Проблема разобраться в этих событиях...

Я попробовал поразбираться.

Создаём консольное приложение (.NET FW 4.7).

Устанавливаем nuget-пакет Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent.

Технология требует прав администратора. Поэтому добавляем в проект манифест и пишем в нём строку:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Код:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Parsers;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Parsers.Kernel;
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session;

namespace ConAppETW
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // create a real time user mode session
            using (var session = new TraceEventSession("Test"))
            {
                // Set up Ctrl-C to stop the session
                Console.CancelKeyPress += (object s, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args) => session.Stop();

                // Turn on the process events (includes starts and stops )
                session.EnableKernelProvider(KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.DiskFileIO |
                                             KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.FileIOInit |
                                             KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.FileIO);

                // Subscribe to a callback that prints the information we wish
                session.Source.Kernel.FileIOCreate += Kernel_FileIOCreate;

                session.Source.Process(); // Listen (forever) for events }
            }
        }

        private static void Kernel_FileIOCreate(FileIOCreateTraceData data)
        {
            if (data.ToString().Contains(@"C:\Test\"))
                Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске даём согласие UAC.

`Keywords` - это то, что мы хотим отслеживать. Не уверен, правильный ли это набор.

`FileIOCreate` - событие, которое будем отслеживать. Это не создание файла, а вообще любые события с ним, как я понял. Пробовал также `FileIORead`, но что-то не зашло...

В обработчике события (а их будет очень много) фильтруем нужные нам. Я сделал просто проверку на путь к искомой папке. Если в этой папке, например, открыть текстовый файлик блокнотом, то события появляются.

---

Это лишь набросок. Если кто-то получше въедет в тему (есть желающие?), то я с готовностью поставлю плюсик и вообще на основе хорошего сообщения можно будет сделать ответ-закрывашку.

Comment: Хм... Странно, что чтение txt файлов через блокнот не отслеживается, хотя чтение других файлов отслеживается...