# Отловить открытие папки в проводнике

Tags: c#

Можно как-то отловить открытие папки в проводнике на c# и передать путь в мою программу? Пытаюсь создать свой клон китайского clover'a [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это возможно, например, с помощью технологии ETW. Вот тут [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1016677/184217) на похожий вопрос.

Comment: Воу, спасибо большое!